# How display outlines in a Map, only from a scale, but the colored polygon in all scales?

Tags: shapefile, mapserver

I want to display a shape with UMN-Mapserver. It has different coloured polygons and also outlines. But I want to display the outlines only, from a specific scale. I could add `MINSCALE 150000`, but in that case the polygon is completely not rendered, if that doesn't match. How I display the polygon without outline in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should define different [classes](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/class.html#class) whithin your [layer](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html) that has individual symbols and different max-min scales.

HTH
Nicklas

Comment: But I want to display the same class differently in different scales.

Comment: Why? Are you sure that you don't mean you want to display the same layer differently in different scales? You then have everything exactly the same in the different classes (I even think you can define the common parameters on layer level instead) except your symbol and max-min scale.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. This means I can create two classes with the same expression, but different MINSCALE and OUTLINE? I try it out. Thanks.